# Reversing order of graphics file extensions with `TikZscale`

Tags: graphics, tikzscale

I am using the `tikzscale` package and having trouble with the search order of different graphics files. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{foo}
\end{document}
```

If I have both `foo.tikz` and `foo.pdf` on `TEXINPTUS`, then `foo.tikz` gets used. I would like to reverse the search order so that `foo.pdf` is preferred. Specifically, I would like to add the `tikz` extensions to the end of `\Gin@extensions` instead of the beginning.

Comment: if it follows normal includegraphics rules extensions are tried in the order specified by eg `\def\Gin@extensions{%
            .png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,%
            .PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,%
     .eps%
          }%` or `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` which is same thing really

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see edit. I know, the problem is it sticks the `tikz` extensions at the beginning and I want them at the end. Once they are there, I don't know how to easily get rid of them. I also don't know how to prevent them from getting there in the first place.

Comment: shrug `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.tikz}` wiill just overwrite whatever was there and specify whatever you want